# How To copy object by value using jquery 

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I'm having an issue with this check box :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="hideTempSeries" checked="checked" value="0" /> 
     Temperature <br />
<input type="checkbox" id="hideFlowSeries" checked="checked" value="1" /> 
     Flow <br />
<input type="checkbox" id="hidePressSeries" checked="checked" value="2"/> 
     Pressure <br /> 
<input type="checkbox" id="hideCondSeries" checked="checked" value="3" /> 
     Conductivity  <br />
```

.. and this jQuery function that sends an array of this check box values to a function called 
 `removePanes(checkedArray)`  " every time any of the check boxes have changed "

```
   $("#tools :checkbox").change(function(){
       if($(this).prop('checked')){// when Checked

       }
       else{// when unChecked
       var checkedArray = [] ; 
        $("#tools :checkbox").each(function(index,value){
           if($(this).prop('checked') == false){checkedArray.push($(this).val())}

        });
        removePanes(checkedArray) ;
       }
```

**removePanes() function**

```
   function removePanes(id){
       var removeUncheckedSeries = $.map(newSeries , function(index,value){
        for(var i=0 ; i < id.length ; i++){  
            if(index.yAxis == id[i])return null;
        }  
       return index ;
       });
       var modified = $.map(removeUncheckedSeries, function(index,value) {
        index.yAxis = 15 ; 
        return index ;
       });
      console.log(modified) ;
    } ;
```

this is  [newSeries[] Object](http://screencast.com/t/P8MFrhzK)

The `removePanes(checkedArray)`  function then takes this array and removes all the objects equivalent to the unchecked values from : `newSeries[]` object

Then it sets all the yAxis values equal to 15.

This function is not working.

*Because each time the check box changed the function doesn't reload the newSeries[] object it just modifies it on the last change.*

What it does is, the first click works fine and then it set all the yAxis to 15. When I unchecked any other boxes since all the yAxis equal to 15 and the jQuery array send value from 0 to 3 nothing happened.

**QUESTION**: How can i make the `removePanes(checkedArray)` reload with the `newSeries[]` object each time a change on check box trigger?

Comment: Where is the `newSeries` object. Can you please show that?

Comment: a simplified demo in [jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/) would help, not really clear what the issue is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> That is happening because objects are by default copied by reference
>   in Javascript.

So if you change any property of copied object from anywhere it will affect all others. To copy an object by value only(or clone) you can use jQuery's `$.extend()` method like Jonh Resig(Yes he himself) showed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/122704/344304

```
var newObj = $.extend(true, {}, oldObj); // deep copy
```

So change your `removePanes` function like following

```
function removePanes(id) {
        var seriesCopy = jQuery.extend(true, {}, newSeries);
        var removeUncheckedSeries = $.map(seriesCopy, function(obj, index) {
            return   $.inArray(obj.yAxis,id) == -1 ? obj : null;
        });
        var modified = $.map(removeUncheckedSeries, function(obj, index) {
            obj.yAxis = 15;
            return obj;
        });
        console.log(modified);
    };​
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/w2KS2/

Comment: Another idea is using $.extend on page load to simply store the origninal data to a copy, then in change handler when checkbox unchecked use $.extend to update `newseries`.

Comment: @charlietfl, Yeah that can be done too, I just went with his organization.

Comment: +1 for solution, I was thinking about it also and just threw my concept in

Comment: @Joy Thanks i never know that about objects :)

Comment: @charlietfl, I am not quite getting it how the objects can be updated using `$.extend` inside the change handler in this case, as they are not associated with keys.  If you dont mind, can you please modify the fiddle with your way, when you have some time, I would like to learn that way too, as it wont need this extra function. Thanks.

Comment: I really didn't dig deep into object from looking at image..poor way to present data

Comment: Can your way be implemented with the dummy object I used in the fiddle? Because I am feeling somehow This function can be omitted.